# How to access a JSON element which has ':' in its name using PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, rss, decode

I am parsing a RSS feed using PHP but the problem is that is has some names like:

```
[im:collection] => stdClass Object
  (
        [label] => Doo-Wops & Hooligans (Deluxe Version)
  )
```

I am doing json_decode() then:

```
foreach($json->content as $con){
  echo $con->im:collection->lable . "<br />";
}
```

but it shows an error....
plz help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one possible way

```
$name_space = 'im:collection';
$con->$name_space->lable ...

/* or */
$con->{'im:collection'}->label ...
```

PS: personally I prefer declare a variable for reusable

Comment: Or alternatively: `$con->${'im:collection'}->lable`

Answer (score 2):

If you decode the JSON as associative array (set second parameter of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to `true`), it becomes:

```
$con['im:collection']['label']
```

Complete:

```
foreach($json['content'] as $con){
    echo $con['im:collection']['label'] . "<br />";
}
```